# Simple way to make GPU to do calculation

Tags: c#, c++, bitmap, gpu, gpgpu

This is my code to remove the Red channel of an image.
Is there any way to make it on GPU?

Actually what I want is, 
I've a source bitmap data(pointer) and a destination bitmap data(pointer).
I want to make some calculations on SOURCE BITMAP and put the result to the DESTINATION BITMAP.

This code works just fine but I'm dealing with large images. That's why I want GPU to make that calculations but I dont want to use CUDA or ATI's SDK. Because If I use CUDA or ATI's SDK's, I'm going to need this Graphic Cards. That's why I need something that works on ALL GRAPHIC CARDS. I've tried to use DirectX but, I didn't see anything like that calculation...

Is there any library to make GPU to do that?

```
 private unsafe void testX()
    {
        Bitmap sourceBmp = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\cc.jpg");
        BitmapData sourceBmd = sourceBmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, sourceBmp.Width, sourceBmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        IntPtr sourcePtr = sourceBmd.Scan0;
        uint* pSource = (uint*)sourcePtr.ToPointer();

        Bitmap destinationBmp = new Bitmap(sourceBmp.Width, sourceBmp.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        BitmapData destinationBmd = destinationBmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, sourceBmp.Width, sourceBmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        IntPtr destinationPtr = destinationBmd.Scan0;
        uint* pDest = (uint*)destinationPtr.ToPointer();

        int _w = sourceBmp.Width;
        int _h = sourceBmp.Height;

        for (int j = 0; j < _h; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _w; i++)
            {
                *pDest = (*pSource) & 0xff00ffff;
                pDest++;
                pSource++;
            }
        }

        sourceBmp.UnlockBits(sourceBmd);
        destinationBmp.UnlockBits(destinationBmd);
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\deneme2.jpg"))
            File.Delete(@"C:\deneme2.jpg");
        destinationBmp.Save(@"C:\deneme2.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        testX();
    }
```

And finally, I've tried too many things such as CUDA, OpenGL, OpenCL and ATI's SDK and I needed to download at least 300MB of file to work with theese SDK's.  So, What I need is a SMALL SIZED library or header that works with ALL Graphic Cards. Thank you for your helps and answers.

Sorry about my English by the way.

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to use CUDA, why are you posting this to the CUDA tag? The GPGPU tag would be more appropriate. You may consider using OpenCL, which might help you to run your code (once written) on CUDA and non-CUDA cards. I'm voting to close this non-question post. Next time try to use a title related to the post you are writing below. StackOverflow is a community. Posting question, you will receive help from others. Appropriate titles may help other users to find a solution to their own problems if similar to yours.

Comment: It yields a paradox if you ask for a library to do it, yet do not want "CUDA or _something else_", because "library" is an element of the set "something else".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard portable method of GPGPU programming is OpenCL. It works on all GPU.
For Intel processors it works on the integrated GPU starting from IvyBridge. On SandyBridge, the CPU actually do the work.
OpenCL support comes with the graphics driver.

**Edit**
For Windows you can try [C++ AMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137.aspx).

Comment: But he didn't want to use CUDA or _something else_.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think, that you will see any performance benefit using GPU for such a trivial operation. You need to copy the source image data to device memory, perform your processing and copy the result image data back to host, which both cost some time.

You can rewrite your code, consider Stride (length of the bitmap rows is aligned to 4 bytes). Help the compiler understand, what you are doing. Prefer array indexing instead of pointer incrementation in the loop.

```
int _ss = sourceBmd.Stride; // correct length of a row
int _sd = destinationBmd.Stride;

for (int j = 0; j < _h; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _w; i++)
    {
        // each iteration of the internal for loop is now independent
        pDest[i] = pSource[i] & 0xff00ffff;
    }
    pDest+=_sd;
    pSource+=_ss;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is not any library for the GPU, instead you can always write one according to your needs.